# Do-While didn't loop back but let the value pass through

Tags: c

I tried to make a program to add a string to a set of strings but the checking for existing string part didn't work. It just passes the do-while and add straight into the list.

```
void Add(char index[MAXN][24], int *pi)
{
    char name[24];
    int n, name_check;
    do {
        printf("Add a student : ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%23[^\n]", name);
        name_check = 1;
        for (n = 0; n < *pi; n++)
            if (strcmp(name,index[n]) == 0) 
                {
                    printf("Existing name found.\n");
                    name_check = 0;
                    n = *pi - 1;
                }
    } while (!name_check);
    strcpy(index[*pi], Trim(name));
    (*pi)++;
    printf("Added.\n");
}
```

Comment: Presumably it didn't print `Existing name found.` either.  So `name_check` was `1` and the loop exited.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show the verbatim output for a given input.

Comment: out of your problem *fflush(stdin);* does nothing, do not do "*n = *pi - 1;*" just do a *break*

Comment: @TomKarzes Yes, that's the case.

Comment: @hanie surely the OP want the reverse, to not duplicate names in the array

Comment: @Jabberwocky The output was just "Added" no matter what I typed in and as other person said, name_check didn't change.

Comment: @bruno Yes that is the case.

Comment: @Miguel that is an important information that you should have mentioned in the question. That means that `strcmp(name,index[n])` is never NULL, which means that the problem is most likely outside your function and you called your function with bogous data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problems comes from that line :

> ```
> scanf("%23[^\n]", name);
> ```

you read the name up to the newline, the newline is **not** read, and because *fflush(stdin);* does nothing the newline is still available, so after you read one name in the very first call of *Add* the next times the input contains just the newline and nothing is read, so you use *name* not initialized with an undefined behavior

replace the line by

```
scanf(" %23[^\n]", name);
```

doing that you bypass the possible newline and also the other spaces starting the input, that also have the great advantage to not limit the length of the read name to 13 in case the input start by 9 spaces

doing the minimum, so removing the useless *fflush* and modifying the format of the *scanf* and adding a *Trim* doing nothing :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * Trim(char *s)
{
      return s;
}

#define MAXN 10

void Add(char index[MAXN][24], int *pi)
{
    char name[24];
    int n, name_check;
    do {
        printf("Add a student : ");
        scanf(" %23s", name);
        name_check = 1;
        for (n = 0; n < *pi; n++)
            if (strcmp(name,index[n]) == 0) 
                {
                    printf("Existing name found.\n");
                    name_check = 0;
                    break;
                }
    } while (!name_check);
    strcpy(index[*pi], Trim(name));
    (*pi)++;
    printf("Added.\n");
}


int main()
{
  char index[MAXN][24];
  int p = 0;
  int i;

  Add(index, &p);
  Add(index, &p);
  for (i = 0; i != p; ++i)
    puts(index[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
/tmp % gcc -Wall d.c
/tmp % ./a.out
Add a student : aze
Added.
Add a student : aze
Existing name found.
Add a student : qsd
Added.
aze
qsd
/tmp %
```

I encourage you to always check the value of *scanf*, if you did you was able to detect it returns 0 except the very first time and you found your error.

an other problem occurs, the spaces at the end of the name are not removed by *scanf*, *immediately* after you read the name you need to trim it *then* to compare it with the memorized names. In your code if we forget the newline not flush and you enter "aze" then "aze " etc you will save two times "aze" (of course all inputs without the '"')

Out of that your program can be simplified, for instance you do not need *name* because you can read in *index[*pi]* directely and save the *strcpy*, *name_check* is also useless because you can check the value of *n* after the loop or move the end of the function into the loop then return etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I think the problem is as @Jabberwocky described. Your codes work just fine itself but didn't when I tried to change mine. And unfortunately, my teacher prohibited the usage of gets and puts.

Comment: *gets* must not be used for sure, it is very dangerous, I speak about *fgets* in my answer

Comment: Apparently, the trim function was the issue and it just fixed itself after I cleaned the mess of my code. And I said gets to represent anything beside that scanf, I don't know why my teacher disliked student using stuffs ahead but gotta turn my head that way.

Comment: @Miguel **never** use *gets*, use *fgets*. I edited my answer in case you cannot use *fgets* too, and even you can use it warning the call to trim is wronly placed, read the end of my answer

Comment: @Miguel I edited my answer again to simplify it, speaking about " %23s" immediately